# Is it possible to make PandaBoard as Bluetooth Headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, pandaboard

I have a requirement to make Pandaboard as Bluetooth Headset. Is it possible to achieve this?

I followed below URL to flash the source code into sdcard. Before flashing I modified system/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf file. In the audio.config file I enabled HFP=true.

URL: https://releases.linaro.org/13.04/android/panda/

After doing this I tried to connect to bluetooth device via following Android-java

```
 UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 m_oBluetoothSocket = btDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID); 
 m_oBluetoothSocket.connect();
```

I also tried connecting without UUID like below

```
                         Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                         m_oBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));

                         m_oBluetoothSocket.connect();
```

I was unable to connect to device I see invalid argument exception.

If I try to run the code on Android mobile I am able to connect and send AT command.

But in mobile I am not able to make it as handsfree, I have done a related post for it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246344/is-it-possible-to-make-my-old-phone-as-handsfree-and-establish-connection-betwee

Comming Back to Pandaboard is my approach correct? How to make Pandaboard Bluetooth has Headset??

Please share thoughts on this....

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it can be difficult. Do you have a particular phone you want to have it work with? If your solution doesn't need to be universal among all the Android phones, then it will be easier.

Comment: I have android Phone, If I get solution to make a particluar phone[my Android Phone] to work it is more than enough. Pandaboard should act like handsfree. So when I get call in my phone I should be able to receive and answer in Pandaboard. Is is possible? If yes how to achieve it?? I have pretty idea it can be done using Handsfree Profiling by sending AT commands, but I am not able to stream audio via bluetooth and answer call...   Please share some thoughts....

Comment: Below Android 4.2, do not use the default android api for bluetooth, use the Motorola Mobility Android bluetooth stack (if your phone uses the Motorola chipset for bluetooth), or use the Broadcom Bluetooth Android stack (if your phone uses the Broadcom chipset). If you want it to work on *all* phones between 2.x and 4.2, you'll have to use both third party stacks at the same time and test for each one. If you're doing this for school, the easiest would be to purchase/borrow one of the newer phones with Jelly Beans on it and do it with that.

Comment: I have purchased Nexus 4 and Nexus 7. I have updated Android to 4.3. I believe it has Jelly Bean. Now In Nexus 4 I have inserted my sim card and Nexus 7 acts as Headset. Now If I get call in Nexus 4, I am unable to receive and speak in Nexus 7. Both are connected via bluetooth. Any modifications are required?. Please share some thoughts.  Atleast I should be able to achieve to listen song in Nexus 7 that is playing in Nexus 4.....